# Can I apply new security patches on Prestashop 1.7.2.4?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have a store running Prestashop 1.7.2.4 (with Symfony 2.8.27) with tons of customized files, theme, modules etc.. I just can't upgrade to newer Prestashop versions otherwise i will loose a lot of work in a blink of an eye.

My question is simple, can I apply prestashop version by version from 1.7.2 up to 1.7.8 security patches on my actual installed PS ? That is including Symfony vulnerable issues.

What is your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Prestashop security patches applied over time are listed [here](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/security/advisories) , you should search the pull requests related to those advisiories and apply / cherry pick them manually on your release.

This can be a hard task though, especially from such an old version.

Generally, I suggest to move your core changes to modules / overrides so that you can update safely to latest version, so you can also benefit of PHP 7.4 support (note that themes and third party modules will not be overwritten during upgrade).